# Hadoop cluster not listening on port that I configured. What is wrong?

Tags: networking, rhel, hadoop, connectivity

I set up a Hadoop cluster with RHEL 7.4 servers.  There is no firewall between them.  I am running Hadoop 3.0.  On the namenode the core-site.xml file is configured to use port 54310.

I run this command: `hdfs dfsadmin -report`

But I get this error (but I 1.1.1.1 is the IP address that I see):

```
report: Call From servera/1.1.1.1 to servera:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

On the NameNode I have used this command:

```
netstat -anlp | grep 54310
```

It does not show any listening service.  I can use start-yarn.sh and start-dfs.sh.  The NodeManager, SecondaryNameNode, ResourceManager and DataNode all start.

I ssh localhost and use `lsof -i`.  I see different ports and connections.  I do not see anything on port 54310.

From a different server port 54310 is accessible.

Why is port 54310 not listening?  I want to run an `hdfs dfsadmin -report` command.  What should I do?